# Inserting semicolon between two names

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new in vba. How I include semicolon between two names. After inserting the semicolon I need to apply custom style for that I am using the following code

```
Public Sub MakeAuthor()
        ApplyParaStyle ActiveDocument.Styles("author"), False
        Application.ScreenRefresh
End Sub
```

INPUT

```
Sam S,1 Manu D,2 Ananthu-krishna D,3 vivek dk,4 sachin Lee,5 
    Alexander won,6 Binoy S,7 brett Lee,8
```

Output

```
Sam S,1 Manu D,2; Ananthu-krishna D,3; vivek dk,4; sachin Lee,5; 
    Alexander won,6; Binoy S,7; brett Lee,8
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop the string, when you find a digit followed by a space insert a `;`

```
List = "Sam S,1 Manu D,2 Ananthu-krishna D,3 vivek dk,4 sachin Lee,5 " & vbCrLf & _
       "    Alexander won,6 Binoy S,7 brett Lee,8"

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Len(List) - 1
    If Mid$(List, i, 2) Like "# " Then
        i = i + 1
        Mid$(List, i, 1) = ";"
    End If
Next

'if you want a space after ;
List = Replace$(List, ";", "; ")

Debug.Print List
```

Comment: Thank you for the information provided but what I actually need is that, when I select the entire name list of authors manually, a semicolon has to be generated after each name.